# Django: Only showing the users own data

Tags: django, authentication, model, private

I have built an application where I list people and companies. Each entry of peoples and companies are owned by a user.

```
owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='+', null=True, blank=True)
```

I'm wondering how I can show only posts owned by the specific user in each view. So that only the companies added by the user are shown, not every entry by every user.

I guess an if request.user = people.owner might work, but is this really the best way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question.  Just filter the query results where user = owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're finding the relevant models in the view, filter by user:

```
 people = People.objects.filter(owner=request.user).filter(...)
```

If you want to factor this out a bit, you could use a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) with a relevant method, which would look something like

```
people = People.objects.for_current_user(request).filter(...)
```

but of course that doesn't save much typing, since you still need to pass in the `request` object – but if you wanted more complicated logic (e.g. superusers can view all people), then this would be handy.

Comment: FYI: You can pass querysets, not just models, to methods like `get_object_or_404` and `get_object_or_404`. So you can do something like `person = get_list_or_404(People.objects.filter(owner=request.user), pk=some_id)`. That would get the particular object as normal, but force it to be related to request.user, or it would still return a 404.